# Multithreading with non-thread-safe CIFilter

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, exc-bad-access

The [docs for `CIFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say that the class is not thread-safe and that "each thread must create its own `CIFilter` object". I am doing just that, but I still get very frequent bad access crashes. Example code which results in a crash:

```
- (CIImage *) outputCIImage {

  CIFilter *monochromeFilter =
  [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMonochrome" keysAndValues:
   kCIInputImageKey, self.inputCIImage,
   @"inputColor", [LSMonochromeFilter CIColorForFilterColor:self.color],
   @"inputIntensity",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

  return monochromeFilter.outputImage;
}
```

This code is being called from up to 10 threads in parallel. I can't figure out the cause, as it looks like the `CIFilter` instances between threads should be completely isolated from one another. Any ideas?

Comment: Just because the filters are separate per thread, that doesn't mean that the resources they access are separate per thread. If you put a mutex or some other type of lock or synchronization around your use of CoreImage, does the problem go away?

Comment: Great, that seems to have solved the problem! Thanks! Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: I've added it as a full answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the filters are separate per thread, doesn't mean that the resources they access are separate per thread. It seems like you need to put a mutex or some other type of lock or synchronization around your use of CoreImage.